# Сгенерировать квадратный двойной массив, где сумма элементов на контуре квадрата равна сумме элементов внутри квадрата

Tags: c#, массивы, матрицы

Ума не приложу, как решить задачу.

Создать программу, которая будет генерировать квадратные двойные массивы произвольного размера такие, что сумма элементов на контуре квадрата у них будет равна сумме элементов внутри контура.

Comment: Что, большая проблема посчитать, сколько элементов на контуре и сколько внутри? Или проблема составить два набора чисел этой длины с равной суммой? или раскидать элементы набора по местам? В чём затык-то?

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Примерно так, думаю:

- берете произвольный размер x;
- размер массива (количество элементов) = x^2;
- размер внутренней части массива = (x-2)^2;
- сгенерировать контур рандомно и записать его сумму:

  ```
   var k = 0;

   for (i from 0 to x-1) {
     for (j from 0 to x-1) {
       if (i = 0 or i = x-1) and (j = 0 or j = x-1) {
         var t = random number;
         array[i,j] = t;
         k = k + t;
       }
     }
   }
  ```
- сумма элементов контура хранится в `k`;
- сгенерировать (x-2)^2 чисел, которые в сумме дадут `k`, и рассовать их во внутреннюю часть массива примерно тем же способом, только изменив условия для элементов массива;